# finding the action name inside post method of an ascx - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial control **formy.ascx** that I am using on a lot of pages that contains a form.

When I click submit on the partial control, following function handles the form submission.

```
[ActionName("FormyTemp"), AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult FormyTemp(FormCollection result)
```

Now, I need to know what page i.e. action I was on when this form was submitted.

I tried passing `(string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]` as one of the form parameters, but it's telling Formy as the action when that is just a partial control. How should I go about doing this? I can't just look at the URL because some of my URL's are like **domain.com/actionName** and some of them are like **domain.com/controllerName/actionName**.

Also, please don't tell me to use RenderPartial...I need to use RenderAction

Comment: Where does the action method FormyTemp() that you showed above currently reside?  This partial view completely encapsulates the form? Are you seeking to post the entire page back or have you considered doing an AJAX submit of just the form contained on formy.ascx?

Comment: FormyTemp resides in HomeController where Formy resides. Yes, the partial view completely encapsulates the form. I am using regular Html.BeginForm, so it's a regular post, not an Ajax one.

Comment: are you looking for the Referrer?

Comment: referrer? Url-referrer... No. Action-Referrer? I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you need to know the action of the *Parent* form, not the individual RenderAction that rendered the partial.  In that case you can use the following:

```
ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
```

Answer (score 0):

When rendering the action:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Formy", new RouteValueDictionary { 
    { "ParentAction", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] } 
}); %>
```

and the Formy action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Formy(string parentAction)
{
    // the parentAction parameter will have the desired value,
    // so you can pass it to the view model Formy.ascx is strongly
    // typed to and include it as hidden field in the form. When
    // the form is later submitted the value will be passed to FormyTemp
    return View();
}
```